# Mixing and matching fabric8 pod templates in Jenkinsfile - Is this really the way it works?

Tags: jenkins, fabric8

On the readme of the [fabric8-pipeline-library](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library) project there is a chapter "Mixing and Matching", which describes how multiple pod templates can be combined to come out with a pod that mixes multiple building capabilities, like having both the maven and docker binaries available.

From this document:

> There are cases where we might need a more complex setup that may require more than a single template. (e.g. a maven container that can run docker builds).
>
> For this case you can combine add the docker template and the maven template together:

```
dockerTemplate {
    mavenTemplate(label: 'maven-and-docker') {
        node('maven-and-docker') {
             container(name: 'maven') {
                sh 'mvn clean package fabric8:build fabric8:push'
             }            
        }
    }
}
```

This mvn call obviously would need maven plus local docker capabilities to be available on the "maven" container.

I have quite a similar problem with one fabric8-enabled project but also need to add the "npm" binary on top. The npm calls are also done from the maven build via exec plugin, so I need a container featuring maven+docker+npm.

While I'm struggling to get this to work I also crosschecked the doc of the [jenkins kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin). It also describes how pod templates can be nested/inherited, but there it does not sound like the result would actually be a single container combining the capabilities of both templates. It just sounds like this mechanism can merely add or modify container configuration on top of the parent template. It does not really combine images.

From this document:

> A podTemplate may or may not inherit from an existing template. This means that the podTemplate will inherit node selector, service account, image pull secrets, containerTemplates and volumes from the template it inheritsFrom.
>
> Container templates that are added to the podTemplate, that has a matching containerTemplate (a containerTemplate with the same name) in the 'parent' template, will inherit the configuration of the parent containerTemplate. If no matching containerTemplate is found, the template is added as is.

This is also the way that I interpret the outcomings of my combination attempts. Combining docker and maven templates does not create a single docker+maven container but two containers "docker" and "maven" inside the pod, where each one has one capability. But there is no container where the capabilities are combined and a mvn call that also needs docker should work.

Why docker+maven still works? I think the maven builder image "fabric8/maven-builder:2.2.297" simply already features docker out of the box. A terminal on a container based on that image can call the docker binary, without any parent templates involved.

So, I think I'm clearly misunderstanding something horribly. Can someone shed some light on this topic?

### UPDATE

Right now I'm much deeper into this topic. No, you cannot combine the capabilities of multiple containers into one with this functionality. I believe the person writing the readme on fabric8-pipeline-library was not really aware of this. You need a single container based on an image that combines everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's technically possible to just combine two docker containers together, so I think the documentation is very misleading.